# MySQL - Joining a table to itself, but keeping original results

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following query:

```
   SELECT a.`graph_value_id`, 
          SUM( a.`value` ) AS value, 
          DATE( DATE_ADD( a.`date_time`, INTERVAL 5 DAY ) ) AS date_time 
     FROM `graph_values` AS a
LEFT JOIN `graph_values` AS b ON ( a.`graph_id` = b.`graph_id` ) 
    WHERE a.`graph_id` = 921
 GROUP BY DATE( a.`date_time` ) 
   HAVING date_time >= MIN( b.`date_time` ) AND date_time <= MAX( b.`date_time` ) 
 ORDER BY a.`date_time` DESC
```

The table is as follows:

- graph_value_id (int)
- graph_id (int)
- value (float)
- date_time (datetime)
- date_created (datetime)
- date_updated (timestamp)

If I remove the LEFT JOIN ( and all references to it ), the query's results are correct.

The problem I'm running into is that the SUM of ( a.`value` ) gets greatly skewed.

The only reason I have joined the second table is so that I can get the MIN and MAX dates available for the same set of data.

Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are effectively creating all matching pars of rows from the two tables and summing the pairs which will give you a factor too high.

Solution: Use one derived query to perform your sum, another derived table to get the min and max, then join the two derived tables to get your result.

```
SELECT T1.graph_id, T1.col1, T1.col2, T2.col1, ...
FROM (
    SELECT graph_id, SUM(...) AS total
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY ...
) T1
JOIN (
    SELECT graph_id, MIN(...) AS minfoo, MAX(...) AS maxfoo
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY ...
) T2
ON T1.graph_id = T2.graph_id
```

Comment: Do you have an example or tutorial I could follow to do something like that? Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @Kerry: I've posted some example code. I think you'll find this stuff in any SQL book.

Comment: @Kerry A highly pseudocoded example: `SELECT columns FROM (SELECT SUM FROM TABLE x GROUP BY y) sum JOIN (SELECT MIN, MAX FROM TABLE x GROUP BY z) minmax ON sum.id = minmax.id [...]`  ...Or, just read Mark's edits. :)